# SSIS Variables vs Parameters (SSIS Denali)

Tags: ssis

1. What is the difference between Variables and Parameters in SSIS Denali?
2. If there is any difference then What is that which Variables cannot do that Parameters can   do ? or vice versa.
3. When should one go with SSIS Parameters and Variables?

I tried searching on Google, but I failed to get some information.

Thanks In Anticipation!

Comment: It's about the lifecycle and scope.
Refer to the following video for the detailed demo with example to get more information on this topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7MN4jCpY98

Answer (score 47):

I think a little bit background will be beneficial to understand the Parameter concept. Here I will explain it in the context of comparing with Variables. To fully grasp the Parameter concept, you might need to look up for the new Project Deployment Model, Environment, Build Configuration as well..

### Usage Of Variable

With SSIS prior 2012, if we need to pass any external values to the package before the execution (as we all do all the time), I normally use configuration file (or a couple of other ways). Say we have a file server, which will be used to access a shared file, I will use variable to store the server name, and expose this variable to the configuration file. If the actual file server is changed (dev env to test env etc.), we just need the change the value of that variable in the configuration file and SSIS package remains intact.

Everything looked good, but there are a couple of things that I always ask myself why and could not figure out why:

1. 100% of the time when I am exposing variables to configuration file, I just expose the "Value" properties. Why does SSIS allow to expose all the other variable properties?
2. Why does SSIS not have "private" variable? By "private" I mean when I chose the variables to configure, the "private" ones just did not get shown on the pick list. The SSIS package could have dozens of variables, for the internal value-holders, what's the point to expose them? Why I have to scroll all the way to find the only one I need to expose?

### New Project Deployment Model

SSIS 2012 introduces a new deployment model, Project Deployment Model. For short, this model deploys SSIS project as a single unit to SQL Server SSIS catalog, and **package configuration is NOT available in this model** (it is available in the old model referenced as Package Deployment Model, with SSIS 2012 you can choose which one to use, 2012 default to the new model).

If we want the pass some values into the SSIS packages, we have to pass them in via **Parameters**, and use SSIS catalog in SSMS to configure the value for the parameters(**only the value, nothing else we can configure**). Parameters and connection managers are exposed automatically in SSIS catalog which can be configured, nothing else previously available via configuration files can be configured in Project Deployment Model (The world is much cleaner). Inside SSIS package, parameters can be used in the same way as variables in terms of building up expressions. **However, parameters can NOT be modified within the SSIS package**, which makes perfect sense. (Why do we need to change a value which is passed in from external? If we have to, pass the value to an variable, and do the changes there..)

### Sum Up

Parameter is only available in the Project Deployment Model, and it provides the only mechanism for passing values from external to SSIS packages in this model. If we think SSIS pacakge as an OO class, Parameters could be thought as public properties, which externals can access and assign value to it (the class itself can/will use it, but cannot modify it). Where Variables could be thought as private variables, which are used internally, external world does not need to know anything about it.

For the old Package Deployment model, there is no Parameter, and the world remains the same.

Answer (score 10):

FYI, in short, variable's value can be changed during the runtime, but parameter cannot. Parameter can help you do the project deployment and you can set it up in SSISDB catalog, while variable cannot.

Answer (score 4):

There are many differences between Variables and parameters, few of them mentioned below:

- `Variables` values can change at run time  but `parameters` value can't change .
- `Variables` can be used only with in the package we can't use it for other package with in the solution but we can use Parameters for multiple package (package exist with in the `Solution Explorer`).

Answer (score 3):

The variables & parameters are similar to that are in java,
we pass/through some values to certain method/task in the form of parameters and we use them in that particular task we cant change those values since they are external things for that method similarly in SSIS the Project Parameters are used to set certain variables or connections dynamically in the package. where as variables are limited internal to the package level.

Answer (score 3):

It works like this:
say you have a project parameter called ServerName:

Lets say you deploy an SSIS package into two integration catalog environments, one which is configured for prod server and another which is configured for test server:

> Then your ServerName 'parameter' will be set in prod with prod server address and in  test environment to contain test server address.
>   If any variable in your ssis package needs a runtime value(say the variable is used to set a connection at run time for prod or test servers respectively) then the variable will use the parameter from above to find the right server to connect to.

So parameters are usually needed in environment specific scenarios.

There are two types of parameters based on how you've configured your solution in Visual Studio: Project parameters or Package parameters. Project parameters are accessible to all packages in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are using send data from outside of the package like usernames, passwords or connectionstrings etc. Variables are using inside of the package. It means you can define a variable in one of your SSIS package and use it in package level.

Answer (score -1):

1. **Parameters** in SSIS are like **Global Constants** in Programming, so if they be applied to the Project can be used anywhere. Their
   highest access would be the whole project.
2. **Variables** as they are named, can be assigned, from a Query or even a **Parameter**, etc. Also their highest level access would the
   package.