# What's the difference between a parameter and a variable in SSIS 2012?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, sql-server-2012-localdb

This is an interview question.

> "What is difference between Parameter and variable in SSIS 2012?"

I am confused about what the actual difference is between them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337431/ssis-variables-vs-parameters-ssis-denali

Comment: Variables in an SSIS package are like you expect.  You define them, and set default values and they can be interacted with from various SSIS blocks to change their values.  They can also be set using configuration files, or command line options when a package is executed.  Parameters references the ability to pass SSIS variables into SSIS blocks so the blocks can interact with them.  I know myself, the most common usage for parameters is Looping constructs or ExecuteSQL statements to provide values for the SQL logic to consume.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS Variables vs Parameters (SSIS Denali)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337431/ssis-variables-vs-parameters-ssis-denali)

Answer (score 0):

- Variables are local to the environment while Parameters are not.
- Variables in different Environment are independent of each other.
- A parameter specifies the data that will be used by a package. You can scope parameters to the package level or project level with package parameters and project parameters, respectively.
- Values to different variable can be supplied through parameters

For Example -
In terms of OOPS, I can say variable are private entities while Parameters are public in nature.